# Combining constant suffixes and portable data types

Tags: c

This seems like a stupidish question that will cost me some reputation scores, but I nonetheless eager to receive feedbacks on this one-

Almost all projects I was working on (embedded systems), either proprietary drivers or 3rd party libraries contained both concepts:

First concept is the use of `UL` suffix (also `UUL`) in constant definitions, for example:

```
#define BIT_0 0x1UL
#define BIT_1 0x2UL
```

Second concept is using the portable types for variable declarations and functions parameters, for example:

```
uint32_t func (uint32_t input1);
```

And suddenly it hit me, though its almost a second nature for me and my colleagues to add `UL` (and `ULL`) suffixes to constants, and use portable types for variables, the combination of both (for example if such a constant will be assigned to, manipulated with, or compared to portable variable) is actually wrong as the first concept is non-portable (`long` can vary in length on different systems) and the second one is.

My question here is this - am I wrong with my enlightenment? is the combination of both concepts actually makes good programming? or am I right and the fact that we use both concept is a result of lack of knowledge?

Comment: No, you are not wrong. Your code is just making a specific assumption about your architecture, where `unsigned long` is the same as `uint32_t`. And this assumption can be right or wrong.

Comment: example: gcc x86 has 32 bit unsigned long, clang iOS has 64 bit unsigned longs

Comment: You are correct. The suffix notation should be used with conditional compilation (`#ifdef`) so that the code uses the correct suffix for each implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not wrong. The suffixes that hardcode "abstract" types like `unsigned long` are not very compatible with using the more concrete types with specified widths.

Sometimes people simply know the mapping, which can make it correct anyway, but it's not as portable or clean.

There are macros you can use for literals, see [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html):

- The macro INT*N*_C shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type `int_leastN_t` (so e.g. `INT32_C(4711)` generates a constant compatible with `int32_t`).
- The same for UINT*N*_C().

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, it was not very nice. I don't think the bolding helps, but I tried something a bit like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it might create issues on some systems.

I would use the following define for compatibility:

```
#define BIT_0 (uint32_t)1U
```

EDIT: If one wants to be fully compatible, the defines should be tossed away

```
uint32_t x = (uint32_t)1U << n;
```

The person reading your code might know the C language, but might not know the magic macros

EDIT2 : Similarly, one can also use the standard **INT***N***_C** format:

```
#define BIT_0 UINT32_C(1U)
```

or

```
uint32_t x = UINT32_C(1) << n;
```